# Composition Metric Spaces

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> Consider a function $f: \mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ such that
>
> - $f(x) = 0$ if and only if $x=0$;
> - $x \ge y$ implies $f(x) \ge f(y)$ and $f(x+y) \le f(x) + f(y)$.
>
> How can I show that if $(X, d)$ is a metric space then $(X, f \circ d)$ is also a metric space?

I know that I need to check the three metric space conditions hold for $(X, f \circ d)$ but I am unsure on how to actually prove that they are true. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. $f\bigl(d(x,y)\bigr)=0\iff d(x,y)=0\iff x=y$
2. $f\bigl(d(x,y)\bigr)=f\bigl(d(y,x)\bigr)$, because $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$
3. $f\bigl(d(x,z)\bigr)\leqslant f\bigl(d(x,y)+d(y,z)\bigr)$ because $d(x,z)\leqslant d(x,y)+d(y,z)$. On the other hand, $f\bigl(d(x,y)+d(y,z)\bigr)\leqslant f\bigl(d(x,y)\bigr)+f\bigl(d(y,z)\bigr)$